# How do I correctly control the slide in/out function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I am a new jQuery programmer so any help you can give me will be mightily appreciated, my current project is trying to design a navigation pane that, when a link is hovered over, a description of that page appears. The problem that continues to occur is that the description appears *after* the link has been moused over, not whilst. This is really starting to annoy me, and I haven't found anything on the web yet.

This is the jQuery I am using:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

$( ".home" ).hover( function() {
    $( ".nav-p-blurb" ).toggle( "slide" );
    $( ".nav-p-blurb" ).text("This is a home page blurb and it will talk about the home page like the other blurbs will talk about their specific pages and hopefully appear correctly");
});

});
```

I don't mind what animation is toggled, anything will work just as well for me. If you can just make it so that the text appears *whilst* the link is being moused over I would really appreciate it.

Here is the HTML and CSS I am using:

html:

```
  <title>website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/navbar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
  <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/navbar.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="document">


 <table class="nav-table">
 <tr>
  <td width="600" class="nav-img">

   <img  class="nav-img" src="img/header-img.png" width="600" height="200">

  </td>

  <td width="100" class="nav-links-td">

  <div class="nav-links">
   <div class="nav-b-div"><a href="#" class="nav-buttons home">Home</a></div>
      <br>
   <div class="nav-b-div"><a href="#" class="nav-buttons about">About</a></div>
      <br>
   <div class="nav-b-div"><a href="#" class="nav-buttons projects">Projects</a></div>
      <br>
   <div class="nav-b-div"><a href="#" class="nav-buttons links">Links</a></div>
  </div>

  </td>

  <td class="nav-blurb">

   <p class="nav-p-blurb"></p>

  </td>
  </tr>
 </table>


</html>
```

css:

```
.document {

margin: 0px;

}

.nav-table {

left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
display: table;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0px;
border-color: gray;


}

td {

padding: 0px;
border: 0px;

}

.nav-img {

left: 0px;
width: 600px;
padding: 0px;

}

.nav-links-td {

left: 50%;
width: 100px;

}

.nav-b-div {

background: #ffffff;
width: 0px;

}

.nav-b-div {

transition: width 0.2s;
-moz-transition: width 0.2s;
-webkit-transition: width 0.2s;
-ms-transition: width 0.2s;

}

.nav-b-div:hover {

background: #efefef;
width: 100%;

}

.nav-buttons {

text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 16px;
padding-left: 5px;

}

.nav-blurb {

height: 100px;
background: #efefef;
overflow-x: visible;


}

.nav-p-blurb {

text-decoration: none;
color: #1C1C1C;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 16px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
position: fixed;
top: 16px;
overflow-x: visible;

}
```

Once again, I will appreciate any help, even if only tips for my HTML and CSS.

Thankyou.

Comment: Can you create a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a separate function for each menu button I will add a data field to each href, which contains the text to be displayed and I will run the function in the next way:

```
$(".nav-buttons").hover(function () {

$(".nav-p-blurb").show();
$(".nav-p-blurb").text($(this).attr("data-mytext"));
});
```

Keeps the script more clear and easier to overview in feature.

See a full set working set: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e27AZ/)

**UPDATE:**
Based on user request I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e27AZ/2/) code with a fadeIn / Out effect
Please see below:

```
$(".nav-buttons").hover(function () {
$(".nav-p-blurb").stop();
$(".nav-p-blurb").fadeTo(0,0);
$(".nav-p-blurb").text($(this).attr("data-mytext"));
$(".nav-p-blurb").fadeTo("slow",1);
});
```

**LAST UPDATE**
As user requested, he will like the text to also slide left-right same way as the menu. Please see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e27AZ/3/) the updated fiddle. To do a similar effect you will need a div which hides the content than the width is animated.

**UPDATE**

Yes it can, but you have 3 working examples from myself and some other explanation from others as well, so you should at least try to figure it out on your own. Nobody here is writing code for free for others, it's about help and support not about doing the job instead of you. This being said, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xa24F/) the last example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it works really well - but is there no way that the text within `.nav-p-blurb` can be animated?

Comment: What animation do you want to add to it?

Comment: This is so awesome! This works amazingly, but is there a way that the animation direction can be reversed? The project would be perfect if, when hovered, the links complete their animation and _then_ the blurb's animation begins, and it continues in the same direction as the link's animation. This will be awesome if you are able to get it to work. Thankyou for all your help so far, it's absolutely amazing!

Comment: Awesome! Thankyou, and I'll take on board your advice for next time :)

Answer (score 1):

the `hover` method in jquery usually needs 2 handlers, one for `mouseIn`, and one for `mouseOut`. I've modified your code a little bit to include both handlers.

Here is a working fiddle:  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7Whe/)

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Awesome, I didn't realise all I needed to do was add a default state. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

May be this:

```
$(".home").hover(
    function () {
        $(".nav-p-blurb").text("This is a home page blurb and it will talk about the home page like the other blurbs will talk about their specific pages and hopefully appear correctly").show();

    }, function() {
        $(".nav-p-blurb").hide().text("");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes to HTML:

```
  <td class="nav-blurb">
      &nbsp; <!-- add this to your html to make td visible -->
      <p class="nav-p-blurb"></p>

  </td>
```

Changes to CSS:

```
.nav-p-blurb {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1C1C1C;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 16px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    display:none; /* make p invisible */
}
```

Changes to JS:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( ".home" ).hover( 
        function() {
            $( ".nav-p-blurb" ).text("This is a home page blurb and it will talk about the home page like the other blurbs will talk about their specific pages and hopefully appear correctly");
            $( ".nav-p-blurb" ).fadeIn( 1000 );

        }, function() {
            $(".nav-p-blurb").hide().text("");
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Is there any way I can wait 0.2 seconds before starting the fade-in effect? And, if possible, can I wait 0.2 seconds and then have the text appear in a swipe motion? Like how the Links get highlighted?

Comment: $( ".nav-p-blurb" ).delay(200).fadeIn( 1000 );